# Orthogonality with engenvectors of A and A transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I was told about this fact in class but no proof was given:

if v is in the span of egienvectors v2, v3...vn of n by n matrix A, where v1 is the leading eigenvector (eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue) and v2...vn so on, then v is orthogonal to the leading eigenvector of A transpose (v1 of A transpose)

Can someone explain why this is true? I tried to figure out the relationship between eigenvectors of A and A transpose but failed.

Comment: Try the simple case of two distinct simple eigenvalues: what is the relationship between a left eigenvector of one to a right eigenvector of the other?

Comment: The left eigenvector of A transpose is the right eigenvector of A, but how to proceed from this?